# How to add button and label to the scene

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, scenekit, arkit

I am new in Scenekit and ARKit, I wanted to add button and label inside UIView to the scenekit's scene. I am getting the world coordinates by the hit test to place the view but SCNNode don't have `addSubView` Method to add view.

I want to achieve following output :

[image]

My attempts to achieve this :

```
func addHotspot(result : SCNHitTestResult, parentNode : SCNNode? = nil) {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .red

    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = view

    let plane = SCNPlane(width: 100, height: 100)
    plane.materials = [material]

    let node = SCNNode()
    node.geometry = plane

    node.position = result.worldCoordinates
    parentNode?.addChildNode(node)
}
```

error :

[image]

Please suggest the way I can complete it.

Comment: You can use SKLabel and add this node as child node of your root node

Comment: Can you please give me an example?  I also need image view which needs to be tappable for user actions

Comment: First you need that button or label in 3d world of arkit. or just normal as subview in scenekit

Comment: its okay if label and button is 2D.

Comment: Any one can help me it?

Answer (score 0):

To add a `UIView` object to a scene node, you can assign it to the node's geometry material **diffuse** content. It will be added to the node and will maintain its position as you move your device around:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  let view: UIView = getView() // this is your UIView instance that you want to add to the node

  let material = SCNMaterial()
  material.diffuse.contents = view

  node.geometry.materials = [material]
}
```

Comment: added UIView as content I am getting some weired kind of error.

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger Would you please share the error message as well?

Comment: Added error as well. it's not showing me proper error on console.

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger see my updated answer. Use `DispatchQueue` to run on main thread.

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger that's strange, does it only happen when you assign the view?

Comment: I thinks its happenning when I am adding child node